# Return the first datetime where the price is highest

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

| volume | price | datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 400 | 9 | 2021-09-29 04:00:00-04:00 |
| 900 | 22 | 2021-09-29 06:00:00-04:00 |
| 1000 | 31 | 2021-09-29 08:00:00-04:00 |
| 400 | 21 | 2021-09-29 10:00:00-04:00 |
| 1200 | 31 | 2021-09-29 12:00:00-04:00 |

I'd like to find the datetime where the highest price ($31) is.

If the highest price appears twice, return the earlier datetime.

Expected output should be `2021-09-29 08:00:00-04:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`pandas.Series.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```py
row = df.loc[df['price'].idxmax()]
```

Output:

```
>>> row
volume                           1000
price                              31
datetime    2021-09-29 08:00:00-07:00
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: thank you  but i  want the output to contain only datetime, and if there is 2 occurance of the same price, then choose earlier datetime

Comment: Just use `row['datetime']`.